# Use regex find and replace with macro or shortcut in eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse, macros, formatting

I need to format a text file (that has changing file extensions) in eclipse. In this file all lines should be capped at 80 characters and lines shorter than 80 characters should be filled up with blanks.

I can do this with a set of regular expressions I created but I don't want to open search&replace manually all the time.
Is there a way to use a shortcut for the execution of the search&replace macro/shortcut or any other simple method in formatting the file without using any external tools?

Answer (score 0):

Use ctrl+h -> File Search. There is a 'Replace' option that you may apply to all files in your workspace, a specific project, or other contexts. Make sure that you check the "Regular expression" box.